# Icecast song title to html page using node icy

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodejs/express apps building and (shame on me) don't know how to send some data from backend to index.html. This code

```
var icy = require('icy');

var url = 'http://localhost:8002/dno';

icy.get(url, function(res){

    res.on("metadata", function(metadata){
        var parsed = icy.parse(metadata);
        return parsed;
    });
});
```

returns song title json like `{ 'StreamTitle' : 'Songname.mp3' }`. There is stringify method for that. And here's generated by Webstorm/express index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

In order to keep song title fresh i think about `setInterval` method.
Actually i have `index.ejs`. How can i send song title to my index page?